# Plotting Elliptical Orbits

Tags: orbital-motion

I'm trying to plot an elliptical orbit (in Python) of a planet with the Sun in 0, according to the equations:

$$ v_x^i = v_x^{i-1} + a_x^{i-1} \, \Delta t $$
$$ x^i = x^{i-1} + v_x^i \, \Delta t $$
where
$$ a_x = -k \frac{x}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}} $$

Same for the y coordinate. To iterate I use the Symplectic method. Here is my code:

```
pointsx = []
pointsy= []
dt = 1
n = 10.0
i = 0.0
k=4*math.pi**2
x=1
y=0
vx=0
vy=1

while i <= n:
    vx += (-k * x / (x**2+y**2)**(3/2)) * dt
    vy += (-k * y / (x**2+y**2)**(3/2)) * dt
    x += vx * dt
    y += vy * dt
    pointsx.append(x)
    pointsy.append(y)
    i += dt
print(pointsx,pointsy)

plt.plot(pointsx,pointsy)
plt.show()
```

The resulting orbit is supposed to be elliptical, but I get straight a line. How can I change it to plot an elliptical orbit, but using the given relations?

Comment: i have seen your code, it seems right when i change the initial conditions make dt small ,i am getting ellipse

Comment: Yes, the shape is an ellipsis for dt <= 10^-6 but I don't exactly understand why this happens.  Should not it always look like an ellipsis?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using python3. In python 2, $3/2$ is 1 rather than 1.5. You need to be careful with division in python.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it is about debugging code. [so] or [scicomp.se] might be better suited for this question.

Comment: @KyleKanos -- Stack Overflow is pretty much worthless for these kinds of questions (such questions are downvoted and closed in the blink of the eye), and [apparently so is Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16222/how-to-tell-if-symplectic-integrator-is-more-suitable-for-my-problem-and-what-a). These are good questions with a clear answer that currently have no place to live in the stackexchange network.

Comment: @DavidHammen: CompSci should take these types of questions, if they don't then shame on that site for not doing their expressed purpose. Anyway, as things stand currently, debugging code is not part of our question-and-answer-space (cf [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5603/25301)).

Comment: But this isn't debugging code. It's more about math -- and physics.

Comment: @DavidHammen: OP has a trouble with a program and wants someone to fix it, that's debugging code to just about any sensible coder.

Answer (score 4):

You are going to have a hard time getting an ellipse using that integrator with that large of an eccentricity. Those initial conditions result in an eccentricity of 0.975. Symplectic Euler (the technique you are using) does not fare well with large eccentricities unless the time step is very small.

Your time step, on the other hand, is **huge**. The orbital period for those conditions (x=1, y=0, vx=0, vy=1, k=4*pi**2) is about 0.36 time units. Your step size of one time unit is almost three orbits. The only integrators that won't completely bomb out with this huge of a step size are adaptive integrators that use an internal step size that is adjusted based on error estimates.

With symplectic Euler, that huge time step means that the very first step results in a huge jump in velocity, which in turn results in a huge jump in position. Your object exits the solar system on the very first step. Subsequent steps result in small changes in velocity because the object is far from the central body, and getting farther each step.

If you decrease the step size a bit you'll find that the object approaches the central body but then gets kicked out of orbit near periapsis. Decrease it a bit more and the object kinda/sorta orbits a few times before getting kicked out. (Interesting things happen with a step size of about 0.00018). Decrease it even more (step size smaller than 0.0001) and you'll get an elliptical looking orbit that precesses. Decrease it even more and you'll start get something that approaches being a closed ellipse. This needs to be a very small step size.

Symplectic Euler is not that good of a technique; it's only first order. There are second order symplectic techniques that are easy to code. If you want high accuracy, you'll need to look to much more advanced techniques -- and these are not easy to code.